# Android open ContextMenu on short click + pass item clicked details

Tags: android

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.btitle);
              registerForContextMenu(text);
              view.showContextMenu();
              }
            });
       }

     @Override
     public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
       super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
       TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.btitle);
       CharSequence itemTitle = text.getText();
       menu.setHeaderTitle(itemTitle);

       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

     }
```

Hello,

I'm trying to open a contextMenu on short item click.
I've managed to do so only if I add  `registerForContextMenu(getListView());` somewhere but this also triggers contextMenu on long click (which I don't want to happen).

- Tried `view.showContextMenu()` but it doesn't do anything unless I add the `registerForContextMenu(getListView());` .
- Tried registering the clicked item first and then call the `showContextMenu()` but didn't do anything as well...

Also, I want to get the clicked item image + text so I can use them in the contextMenu.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
      super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

      AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
      long itemID = info.position;
      menu.setHeaderTitle("lior" + itemID);
    }
```

> AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = 
>   (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;

gives you more details about the list item clicked.
Then you can use `info.id, info.position` and so on to retrieve the details and use them actions (edit, delete...).

Comment: thanks for this ! i used this to build on getting the item clicked from a custom Adapter.

Comment: Probably it works in ListView, but in my case (RecyclerView) it returned null in `menuInfo`. But thanks for a direction.

Answer (score 63):

I was able to open a context menu on button click with the following code:

```
public void onButtonClickEvent(View sender)
{
    registerForContextMenu(sender); 
    openContextMenu(sender);
    unregisterForContextMenu(sender);
}
```

Just set the onClick property of the button to onButtonClickEvent. A long click won't trigger the context menu, since it is unregistrered right after it is shown.

Comment: @konrad...Superb... Great help !! :)

Comment: +1 - I needed this as part of making a table row clickable, did the job, thank you very much!

Comment: Just saved me a bunch of time as well.  I needed to bring up a quick context menu with a short click.  This answer should be accepted by the OP.

Comment: Note that in the case of a ListView, the sender need to be your listView, not the View of your item, else you'll have bad times.

Comment: How does it solve a problem that ContextMenu doesn't get an item id, image and text?

Answer (score 38):

Regarding opening a context menu on a short click:

The other solutions posted here didn't work for me because I was using a ListFragment. However the following solution seems to work quite nicely for both a ListFragment and a ListActivity (or just any old listview in general):

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
  l.showContextMenuForChild(v);   
}
```

It's much more simple and elegant. In fact, this is actually how the ListView class itself initiates the context menu on a long click.

Comment: While this is the solution I was looking for (+1!), it does not appear to fit what the OP was looking for as the context menu will still display on a long click.

Comment: @Blumer Yea, I know :/ But since the title of the question doesn't make any mention of that caveat, I decided to post my solution for the people like you and I that would stumble upon this question with out having that requirement.

Comment: +1 Using `l.showContextMenuForChild(v)` instead of `openContextMenu(l)` calling `item.getMenuInfo()` in `onContextItemSelected` will return a valid `AdapterContextMenuInfo`.

Comment: Great solution. Actually if you also use the "Action Mode" for long press, action mode overrides the events for context menu. So now I have item click for context menu and long press for action mode at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had BaseAdapter and implemented click on button for each listView item (in getView method):

```
ImageButton menuBtn = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemListMenu);
menuBtn.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        parent.showContextMenuForChild(v);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you add an [OnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) to the view, you should be able to prevent it from showing the context menu on long click.

In onItemClick the `view` parameter is the item view, so you should be able to get ImageViews or TextViews from that:

```
view.findById(R.id.my_image_view);
```

Comment: Hi Mayra,
I know... but for some reason it's not getting this. no force close.. just shows the details of the first item in the list.

Comment: public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
   super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
   TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.btitle);
   menu.setHeaderTitle(text.getText());
........
}

Gets only the first item title and not the clicked item.

Comment: You should be doing that in onItemClick, not onCreateContextMenu.

Comment: I should be setting a contextMenu title in onItemClick???? before the contextMenu is even created?
menu.setHeaderTitle is only possible under onCreateContextMenu.

Comment: Hmm, so the view that gets passed into onCreateContextMenu is the first item in the ListView?  I think you might be confusing the context menu methods for the activity, and for the list.  You could try using list's showContextMenuForChild to display the context menu instead.

Comment: Nope... read about it at Android API documentation... and tried it.. didn't help.
I've changed it to long click opens the contextMenu and single click allows item sorting but that didn't help either.. still showing only the details of the first item in the list.

:/

Comment: Solved it. Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {               
            mListView.showContextMenuForChild(view);
        }
    });
```