# Creating a context menu on the click of an element inside a listview item

Tags: android

[image]

Clicking the more icon (3 vertical dots anchored to the right of the list item) opens up a context menu in Google Music:

[image]

I'm trying to recreate this with what I'm guessing is a context menu. Documentation says:

> If your activity uses a ListView or GridView and you want each item to
>   provide the same context menu, register all items for a context menu
>   by passing the ListView or GridView to registerForContextMenu().

But I still want the list item itself clickable. I just want a context menu to show up when the user clicks on the more icon like it does in Google Music.

So I tried this:

```
@Override
public void onMoreClicked(ArtistsListItem item, int position, View imageButton) {       
     registerForContextMenu(imageButton);
}
```

onMoreClicked is just part of a custom listener I made to receive onClick callbacks from the list's adapter.

registerForContextMenu is called, but the fragment's onCreateContextMenu method is never invoked:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo info) { //this method is never called
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, info);

    android.view.MenuInflater inflater = mActivity.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.artist_list_menu, menu);
}
```

I ran some breakpoints to check if it was running but it never did. I did the same with the activity's onCreateContextMenu (the registerForContextMenu's class is the fragment, but just to be sure I did it that way) and no dice either.

I'm using ActionBarSherlock, I don't know if that makes a difference but I guess it's worth noting.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Comment: I think Google Music doesn't use a contextual menu, it looks like it, but it might be a FragmentDialog, because of the way it animates. But I'm not 100% sure and I haven't taken a look at your code yet.

Comment: Hmmm looks ok, but it may be a problem with the list (and the buttons) fighting for the Focus? Have you tried adding android:focusable="false" to the buttons?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3611551/2684

Comment: FYI... I am the 3000th viewer.. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, this is what I ended up doing:
In the listAdapter.getItem I attach a listener to each sub view:

```
private Fragment mParentFragment;

public FriendListAdapter(Fragment fragment, ...) {
    . . .
    this.mParentFragment = fragment;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if( convertView == null ){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.friend_layout, parent, false);
    }
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) convertView;
    assert viewGroup != null;

    *
    *
    *

    Button viewMessageButton = (Button) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.b_send_message);
    viewMessageButton.setTag(friend.getHandle());
    viewMessageButton.setOnClickListener(mParentFragment);
    return viewGroup;
}
```

and in the Fragment I just listen to onClick events:

```
public class FriendListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), SEND_MESSAGE_DIALOG);
    }
}
```

Or you can use `PopupMenu` from support v7 Which you can install in Android studio without gradle from Project Structure window.

Choose `Modules` on the left, then `Import Library` navigate to `..../android-studio/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` then in you main project module add **appcompat** as a module dependency.

Comment: You ended up doing nothing?

Comment: Accidentally posted too early ;)

Comment: I'm assuming your solution works, but I'm also 99% sure that it's not really needed, a ListView can be clickable and can contain other views which can display contextual menus. :-)

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure you can do -> public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
  lv.showContextMenuForChild(v);   
}

Comment: You are absolutely correct. EDIT: Oops, I deleted my last comment, sorry. I guess this one will go too.

Comment: hahahah no problem. Relevant info I just found: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3722380/2684