# context menu to show on button click from listview adapter

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have a button on a `ListView` and on clicking that button i want to show a contextmenu defined in my layout.

Problem is the method  `registerForContextMenu` is not recognized by customerlistadapter.
The context menu methods `onCreateContextMenu`,`onContextItemSelected` are overridden in the activity which is showing the `ListView`.

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customforumview, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) 
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.forumtitle);
        holder.txtCategory = (TextView)
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.forumcategory);
        holder.menubutton = (ImageButton)
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuselect);

        holder.menubutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //context menu to be called here 
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtTitle.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.txtCategory.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getCategory());

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have registered correctly your contextMenu in your Activity, you could call your contextMenu with:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    holder.menubutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //context menu to be called here
            parent.showContextMenuForChild(v); 
        }
    ...
});
```

If you want to access to which elements was called in your activity add in your `onCreateContextMenu` like this

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

  AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
  long itemID = info.position;
  menu.setHeaderTitle("lior" + itemID);
}
```

Refer for more info to [@Lior Iluz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3729992/4848308)

Hope this helps!!